# Java How to calculate age with day/month/year?

Tags: java, date, calendar

How to calculate age between `17/08/1992` and `18/06/2013` (`day/month/year`)

i want result     day month year

Comment: @HarryJoy i want code in Java

Comment: Don't just directly ask for code, do some search, try to write some code, then come up with an error if any. -1.

Comment: hay @Hornmike you could use Joda time library `Days.between(startDate, endDate);`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be working

```
    GregorianCalendar d1 = new GregorianCalendar(1992, 8 - 1, 17);
    GregorianCalendar d2 = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 6 - 1, 18);

    d2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -d1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    d2.add(Calendar.MONTH, -d1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    d2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -d1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);

    int y = d2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int m = d2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int d = d2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1;
```

Comment: this code is calculate LeapYear yet ?

Comment: I hope so, java Calendar is definitely aware of leap years

Answer (score 0):

Though I shouldn't be answering this, I've answered this after seeing your reply to @Harry Joy's comment :P

```
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dateOfBirth);
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(currentDate);
cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);
if(cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
      factor = -1; 
}
age = cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) + factor;
System.out.println("Your age is: "+age);
```

Comment: Still you shouldn't have answered, Instead provided some hints to OP since he is learning.

Comment: it wasn't meant for java experts like you, but novices like OP, who didn't know even GOOGLE.

Comment: Actually you are not helping OP but instead you are making him lazzzzzy !!! Now next time he will do same, instead of searching and trying things on his own, he will just put question here hoping you will do his work and answer him :P

Comment: If I had not answered it, some1 or the other would have answered it. And the fact that this question is still not closed, says the rest.